# Bower modules cache on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, bower

I 've been using bower to install client-side dependencies, e.g. jquery and purecss, to my Node.js project. I add the following to my package.json and everything works like a charm - downloading the bower modules at deploy time.

"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }

I was wondering though if it's possible to cache the modules, similar to how node-modules work, so I don't have to download them every-time I deploy my code. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Who told you heroku redownload the modules? if you don't use "postinstall": "bower cache clean && bower install"
the modules are cached

Comment: @BenDiamant have a look at the output of my `git push heroku`

bower jquery#~2.1.3 not-cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.1.3
bower jquery#~2.1.3 resolve git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.1.3
bower jquery#~2.1.3 download https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.3.tar.gz
bower jquery#~2.1.3  extract archive.tar.gz
bower jquery#~2.1.3  resolved git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.3

It doesn't give the impression bower modules are cached.

Comment: `npm install` on the otherside explicitly states "Restoring node modules from cache".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is **no option to do this** in the current nodejs buildpack.

There is a discussion about solving this here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/pull/192/files

Answer (score 1):

Heroku support custom cache directoies:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior